# Repeating elements in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have this list comprehension:

```
[[x,x] for x in range(3)]
```

which results in this list:

```
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
```

but what I want is this list:

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

What's the easiest to way to generate this list?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
[y for x in range(3) for y in [x, x]]
```

Comment: If one wants to generatlize it one could write `[x]*2` instead of `[x,x]`.

Comment: @phimuemue: which would be even slower

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> [i for i in range(3) for _ in range(2)]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 5):

a general solution;

```
m = 3   #the list of integers
n = 2   # of repetitions
[x for x in range(m) for y in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [int(x/2) for x in range(6)]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Maybe using the integer division operator with `x // 2` would be better than `int(x / 2)`? In Python 2.7, `timeit` shows `//` to be a little more than twice as fast, In Python 3.1, nearly three times, for large ranges.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
def explode_list(p,n):
    arr=[]
    track=0

    if n==0:
        return arr    
    while track<len(p): 
        m=1
        while m<=n:
            arr.append(p[track])
            m=m+1
        track=track+1

    return arr
```

Answer (score 0):

You might get away with this:

```
[floor(x/2) for x in range(6)]
```

**edit1**

```
[int(x/2) for x in range(6)]
```

is the more portable solution in the same vein. Although the other presented answers seem better.

Comment: `math.floor()` returns a `float`, so this is not quite the same.

Comment: returns integer in py3k, though

Answer (score 0):

```
[x/2 for x in range(6)]
```

update:

```
[x//2 for x in range(6)] #ok now ?
```

Comment: @Ant: change to py3k syntax is trivial. However the same solution was given by Ned