# list comprehension to repeat element in a list by element value

Tags: python, list-comprehension, python-3.3

I can't quite figure out the code to do this, there are similar posts: [Repeating elements in list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925465/repeating-elements-in-list-comprehension)

but I want to repeat a value in the list by the value in the list

```
In [219]:

l = [3,1]

[i for x in range(i) for i in l]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-219-84d6f25dfd96> in <module>()
      1 l = [3,1]
      2 
----> 3 [i for x in range(i) for i in l]

TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

What I want is a list like so:

```
[3,3,3,1]
```

Also can someone explain the error.

Note I am running python 3.3 here

Comment: Note that the first for-loop runs first, so `i` is undefined there.

Comment: Regarding the error, you must have initialized `i` to a tuple before running the list comprehension, hence you'll get that error in Pytton 3. `range((1, 2)) --> TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[x for x in l for _ in range(x)]
# Out[5]: [3, 3, 3, 1]
```

But I prefer more verbose, yet more straigforward (literal) functions from itertools:

```
from itertools import chain, repeat
list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(x, x) for x in l))
```

Comment: I really like your second answer, it's more readable to me, I'm actually using this to reduce the verbosity in an asnwer I posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152470/computing-spell-lengths-of-data-based-on-equality-in-pandas, for some reason the list comprehension doesn't work for the `spell_len` method in my answer but your itertools one did

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution.

```
l = [3,1]

ll = reduce(lambda a, b: a + [b] * b, l, [])

print ll
```

Comment: Where does reduce come from?

Comment: Please take a look at that https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce

Comment: Is this missing from python 3? I'm using python 3.3

Comment: @EdChum Apparently, in Python3, you have to import it from functools (and of course use print as a function).

Comment: This is very inefficient solution - with every iteration you create `b` new lists, than concatenate them (slow!) to `a` and each other. If you profile it, you find that your solution has around `O(n^2)` complexity...