# Repeat elements in a list n times with n from another list

Tags: python, list, repeat

Perhaps this was asked before in which case I will remove this question but I have two lists:

```
occurence_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
value_list = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

And I want each value to appear the same number of times as the value of the same index from the other list:

```
result = [10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
```

How can this be done?

Comment: very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156745/list-comprehension-to-repeat-element-in-a-list-by-element-value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `itertools.repeat()` and `chain()`:

```
In [6]: from itertools import repeat, chain

In [7]: list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, j) for i, j in zip(value_list, occurence_list)))
Out[7]: [10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
```

Instead of concatenating the repeat objects by `chain.from_iterable` and then converting the result to list you can also use a nested list comprehension:

```
In [12]: [t for i, j in zip(value_list, occurence_list) for t in repeat(i, j)]
Out[12]: [10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
```

Comment: Thanks, works great!

Answer (score 1):

Use `list comprehension`,

```
In [7]: [j for i,j in enumerate(value_list) for _ in range(occurence_list[i])]

Out[7]: [10, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 40, 40, 40, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, also works very well!